# implement imap search on server

Tags: search, imap

I'm currently working on implementing IMAP protocol on our mail server.  This is my first time implementing such a big project and I've so far coded a majority of IMAP commands in the RFC, except the Search command.
I've been searching on the internet and studied postfix algorithm for weeks to see how to write the search command correctly.
It seems Postfix would work until I encountered something like OR OR A B C D ==> (OR (OR A B) C) D
Could anyone point me a direction on how to implement the Search command when there are multiple ORs?

Thank you very much for any help you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be an answer you are going to like, but I'll recommend this anyway -- *don't do this*. IMAP is an extremely complex protocol with a ton of non-obvious corner cases. The baseline version (RFC3501) also leaves many advanced features missing; in order to get reasonable performance, especially with mobile clients, you need to implement quite a few extensions.

If I were you, I would recommend integrating with an existing open-source IMAP server implementation. If you have a fancy storage backend, perhaps you can write a plugin for Dovecot or Cyrus.

If you decide to really reimplement this yourself and this is your first complex project, you will very likely end up with a product which is subtly broken in numerous ways. If your goal is to be able to add a "speaks IMAP" phrase to the sales brochure, well, it will work, but in practice, you will be solving interoperability problems in the next five years at least.

Comment: Jan, thanks for sharing your thoughts. Unfortunately, you are correct about the reason I have to write it from scratch.  It's so that we can put a "Supports IMAP" label on our product. Since we have a home grown mail server, I can only implement this to the best of my ability, or until my boss kicks me out ;) I hope someone who had already been down this road could give me a bit of guidance on how to deal with the complexity of parsing the search command.